# Why can't this stream run in parallel?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

How do I get this to run in parallel? my output is totally sequential and elapsed time is not displayed until everything is finished. This is my first attempt at parallelizing streams so I'm probably missing something obvious to everyone else. But I can't see what is wrong compared to sample code I looked at.

```
public class Paralells {


    void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i<=1000; i++) System.out.println(i);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Paralells> a = new ArrayList();

        a.add(new Paralells());
        a.add(new Paralells());
        a.add(new Paralells());
        a.add(new Paralells());
        a.add(new Paralells());

        long x = System.currentTimeMillis();
        a.parallelStream().forEach(p -> p.run());
        System.out.println("ELAPSED: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-x));
    }

}
```

Comment: You are confusing the parallel stream with asynchronous execution. `a.parallelStream().forEach(p -> p.run());` isn't performed asynchronously, it will wait for the operation to finish before printing `"ELAPSED: ..."`. But the pipeline itself _is_ run in parallel; `forEach` will be invoked concurrently by different threads, try to print the current thread for example, you will see it changes.

Comment: now I understand that the pipline is parallel, but the next statement is not executed until the pipeline is finished, that was confusing me some...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But it is parallel! Experiment this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Paralells {

    private int id;
    public Paralells(int id) { this.id = id; }
    void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i<=1000; i++) System.out.println(id+" "+i);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Paralells> a = new ArrayList();

        a.add(new Paralells(1));
        a.add(new Paralells(2));
        a.add(new Paralells(3));
        a.add(new Paralells(4));
        a.add(new Paralells(5));

        long x = System.currentTimeMillis();
        a.parallelStream().forEach(p -> p.run());
        //a.forEach(p -> p.run()); // sequential
        System.out.println("ELAPSED: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-x));
    }
}
```

An id is set for each element and is used while printing messages. You should be able to observe that the messages are interlaced. Compare with the sequential version (uncomment the appropriate line and comment the parallel version).

Of course, time is collected after everything finished. Time is printed after `forEach`...

Answer (score 0):

I tried your exact code, and it does execute in parallel. I think it may appear as sequential because the `run()` method finishes so fast that the stream hasn't had time to create all the threads.

If you want see that the stream is actually run in parallel, try adding a little `Thread.sleep(10)` call within your loop in the `run()` method.

Now, for the second part, the elapsed time will not be printed before everything is finished. Even though the stream is parallel, it will still be blocking.

Comment: ah I see, my powers of observation are not so great... What happened was that before "switching" output to another thread, 10-20 numbers were spit out for that thread. So it looked sequential.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Parallels implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i<=1000; i++) {
// uncomment this line, if you don't see concurrent execution
//            try { Thread.sleep(1); } catch (Exception e) {} 
            System.out.println(i);
    }   }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Thread> a = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) a.add(new Thread(new Parallels()));

        long x = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(Thread t : a) t.start();

        for(Thread t : a) try { 
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("ELAPSED: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-x));
    }
}
```

1. implement the Runnable interface
2. use *new Thread(new Parallels())* to create the Threads
3. use *t.start()* to start their Execution
4. use *t.join()* to wait for the Thread until it has finished
5. if you don't see any concurrency, insert a *Thread.sleep()* which slows down the Thread and "motivates" the VM to switch to another Thread